# Lost netwok connectivity

Tags: networking, virtualbox

Hope someone can help me, please.
I have an odd one here.  I run a Debian OS with 3CX IPPBX as a virtual machine (Guest) using VirtualBox.  It is running version 9 and the 3CX needs an upgrade that is dependent on the Debian being upgraded to 10.  I tried in the past but it wasn't allowing the upgrade.  HOWEVER, I had parked that as something to do another day.

In the meantime out of the blue I notice about 3 days ago that whilst I could see and open files on the host machine from other machines on the same LAN, I couldn't save them to it or add any, so yesterday I decided to kill two birds with one stone and check it out and also sort the Guest machine upgrades.  The host is running XUBUNTU 21.10 and is up to date.

First I noticed that the resolution was on basic and whilst I could move my cursor about it was doing nothing and I couldn't shut down or open anything or type anything.  I was forced to do a power off to unlock it.  After reboot, I still couldn't sort the resolution and found no Additional Drivers in the repository, so ran updates (including 21.04 to 21.10) and checked all was working and up to date and managed to get the resolution/drivers sorted.  Which the Host seemed to be, but I noticed no network connectivity on the Guest and that was noticeable also in that the handsets were also showing not registered.  After packing in for the night I resumed today.  I can't upgrade the Guest or the 3CX IPPBX because there is no network.  I started fiddling with the network settings in the Guest and the VirtualBox, until I realised that whilst I could get some browser addresses on the Host I was not able to get them all.  I then noticed that I couldn't reach the router from the Host, and so tried pinging from the router to the Host and again, could not be found.  I tried accessing the host from other machines and it can not be found.  Basically, it seems I have a limited network connection on the Host, therefore none on the Guest.

I've been trying Google searches (on another PC) for ideas and looked on the forum here inc the suggested ones, but none have as yet worked.  I can't use any installs as I have no network.

Can anyone help, please?

Comment: With no replies, I decided to reinstall the Ubuntu Host.  Still has issues around resolution and drivers, but this blog doesn't now fit the requirements.

Comment: Discovered that the MAC address of the Guest network had changed.  Resolved by correcting with the origional.